# JSON dynamic field name with Jackson

Tags: java, json, jackson

I use an API that provides a swagger.yaml from it I generated following class:

```
@ApiModel(description="the paginated history of the specification attributes values")
public class SpecificationHistoryResponse  {

  @ApiModelProperty(example = "null", value = "the array of historic values is named with the specification attributes key")
  private List<SpecificationResponse> key = new ArrayList<SpecificationResponse>();
  @ApiModelProperty(example = "null", value = "")
  private Pagination pagination = null;

 /**
   * the array of historic values is named with the specification attributes key
   * @return key
  **/
  public List<SpecificationResponse> getKey() {
    return key;
  }

  public void setKey(List<SpecificationResponse> key) {
    this.key = key;
  }

  public SpecificationHistoryResponse key(List<SpecificationResponse> key) {
    this.key = key;
    return this;
  }

  public SpecificationHistoryResponse addKeyItem(SpecificationResponse keyItem) {
    this.key.add(keyItem);
    return this;
  }

 /* ... */
}
```

Using the API to request a `SpecificationHistoryRespone` for a specific "specification" returns following JSON:

```
{
  "specification_key": [
    {
      "value": "0.02242",
      "source_timestamp": "2017-08-09T13:10:04.177Z"
    },
    {
      "value": "0.0124",
      "source_timestamp": "2017-08-11T13:16:04.177Z"
    }
    /*...*/
  ],
  "pagination": {
    /*...*/
  }
}
```

Using the [`JacksonJsonProvider`](http://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-jaxrs-json-provider/javadoc/2.0.1/com/fasterxml/jackson/jaxrs/json/JacksonJsonProvider.html) I cannot get `specification_key` as it always tries to deserialize a value `key` which does not exist.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay the automatically created code needs quite some editing and should look like this to work with dynamic field names:

```
@ApiModel(description="the paginated history of the specification attributes values")
public class SpecificationHistoryResponse  {

  @ApiModelProperty(example = "null", value = "the array of historic values is named with the specification attributes key")
  @JsonAnySetter
  private Map<String, List<SpecificationResponse>>  key = new HashMap<>();
  @ApiModelProperty(example = "null", value = "")
  private Pagination pagination = null;

 /**
   * the array of historic values is named with the specification attributes key
   * @return key
  **/
  public Map<String, List<SpecificationResponse>>  getKey() {
    return key;
  }

  public void setKey(Map<String, List<SpecificationResponse>> key) {
    this.key = key;
  }

  public SpecificationHistoryResponse key(Map<String, List<SpecificationResponse>>  key) {
    this.key = key;
    return this;
  }
 /* ... */
}
```